# different objects between my server and locally for maven deployment

Tags: maven, java, suid

I use maven and the weblogic-maven-plugin 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT to deploy a .war on a weblogic server (8.1).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>myAppli</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myAppli</name>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>****</artifactId>
        <groupId>***</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdbc2_0-stdext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc2_0-stdext</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <classifier>rc2</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconnect</artifactId>
            <version>5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamail</artifactId>
            <version>win.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>webvision</id>
            <name>nexus</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>nexusAddress</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>weblogicRepo</id>
            <name>weblogic</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>

        <finalName>appli-war-V${application.version}-${application.date}</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <configuration>

                    <name>myAppli</name>
                    <adminServerHostName>myAddress</adminServerHostName>
                    <adminServerPort>myPort</adminServerPort>
                    <adminServerProtocol>http</adminServerProtocol>
                    <userId>id</userId>
                    <password>pwd</password>
                    <packageName>pa-86a-myappl-${application.version}.war</packageName>

                </configuration>

                <dependencies>

                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
                      <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
                      <version>8.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
                      <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
                      <version>8.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>myApply.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <serverSide>true</serverSide>
                    <typeMappingVersion>1.2</typeMappingVersion>
                    <wrapArrays>false</wrapArrays>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>axis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generated-axis-wsdl2java-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.4</source>
                    <target>1.4</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <!-- The ant plugin is used to update the server-config.wsdd -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-serverconfig-wsdd-resource</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                update src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
                                <java classname="org.apache.axis.utils.Admin" fork="true" classpathref="maven.compile.classpath"
                                    dir="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF">
                                    <arg value="server" />
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/src/main/java/myApply/deploy.wsdd" />
                                </java>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}\src\main\webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make shared resources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>myApply-${application.version}</finalName>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>myapplyLib.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>

                    <!-- <docletPath>/path/to/UmlGraph.jar</docletPath> -->
                    <docletArtifact>
                        <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doclet</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1</version>
                    </docletArtifact>
                    <additionalparam>
                        -inferrel
                        -inferdep
                        -quiet
                        -hide java.*
                        -collpackages
                        java.util.*
                        -constructors
                        -inferrel
                        -qualify
                        -postfixpackage
                        -nodefontsize 9
                        -nodefontpackagesize 7
                        -attributes
                        -operations
                        -enumerations
                        -enumconstants
                        -visibility
                        -link
                        "http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/docs/api/"

                    </additionalparam>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                    <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- FileBugs plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                    <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                    <excludeFilterFile>${project.build.directory}/../src/quality/findbugs-exclude.xml
                    </excludeFilterFile>
                    <includeFilterFile>${project.build.directory}/../src/quality/findbugs-include.xml
                    </includeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Eclipse plugin enforces download of source and JavaDoc jars -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>


    <reporting>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Covertura plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.4</source>
                    <target>1.4</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </reporting>

</project>
```

But I'm confronted with this problem:

```
javax.management.ObjectName; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5467795090068647408, local class serialVersionUID = 1081892073854801359
```

I understand that the version of ObjectName are different between the server and in local, but I don't know how can I change this.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a (maven plugin) version difference problem

Answer (score 0):

Paste your complete pom.xml, as well as: what version of java you're using, what version of Java that Weblogic supports. Have you defined a source/target level to use for your compiled classes? By default Maven uses 1.4, if I recall correctly. BEA 8 uses 1.4.x as well (though JRockit). If the SDK you're using is different that the one for WL, then that might be the cause.

Comment: I use jdk1.5.0_22. When I try with jdk1.4.2, I have this error:         `Unsupported major.minor version 49.0`. And yes, Weblogic 8.1 supports 1.4.x.